# Query Help Needed with using COUNT and JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, count

I am looking for help in writing a MYSQL query. I have two tables, one called users and another called switched. The users table has the following structure:

```
uid
first_name
last_name
```

And the switched table:

```
uid (references user table)
switch_number
reg_date
```

The switched table has multiple uid values and I wish to generate a table with the following output:

```
uid | switches
```

Where switches refers to the number of occurrences in the switched table. Could someone please guide me on how to do this using MySQL and PHP. I appreciate any help.

Regards,

Comment: does your user table have anything to do with the desired output?

Comment: Providing sample data and desired output would help better illustrate the problem and desired solution.  At this time I can't see why you would need the first table at all.  `Select UID, count(Switches) from switched group by UID` seems like what your after but I can't tell.  counting switches means NULL switch_numbers will be omitted if that situation exists.

Comment: Screenshots would be great...

Answer (score 6):

This will output the `uid`s found in the `switched` table and their counts

```
select uid, count(switch_number) as switches
from switched
group by uid
```

If you need zero counts too then do

```
select u.uid, count(s.switch_number) as switches
from users u
left join switched s on s.uid = u.uid
group by u.uid
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like that:

```
select uid, Count(*) from switched Group by uid
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, you want a [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) clause in your statement.

Comment: This is not more than a comment.

Comment: Right, sorry for that